# ldap Novell authentication in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication, novell

I'm trying to develop a web application with **Novell LDAP Authentication**.
I have added in my form login.aspx the **Login control** and I have configured the **web.config** in this way:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="LDAP://10.0.0.100:389/cn=admin,o=pippo" name="myConnectionString"/>
   </connectionStrings>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="MembershipADProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="MyADMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, 
         System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
         PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
         connectionStringName="myConnectionString"
         port="389"
         useSSL="false"
         connectionProtection="None"
         connectionUsername="cn=admin,o=pippo"
         connectionPassword="admin"
         enableSearchMethods="true" 
         />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

But when I click on login button i receive this error:

**"This provider can target only Active Directory and ADAM directories."**

I noticed that if I'm wrong password the error message changes to: 
"Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password". So I think that in some way the application is connected with ldap server and communicate with it.

Now the questions...
Which kind of provider I must choose? Or how can I setup the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider in order to make login against LDAP Novell?

In other word, how can develop LDAP Authentication Code to Look Up the User in Novell's LDAP?

Thanks to all in advance

Regards

Comment: Novell?  What's that? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a custom membership provider.  There's an example here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/970391.aspx/1

Comment: Thank you so much,
I have developed a custom membership provider and now it works.